# boolean algebra article/book

Tags: math, boolean, algebra

i got really confused every time when i encounterd bit operations,especially those shifts,rotates,overflow things etc.I wonder if there's any book/article on the web introducing boolean algebra,which could give me  a solid background of boolean algebra,thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two really great books come to mind.

- [Code: The Hidden Language of Computer Hardware and Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735611319)
- [Hacker's Delight](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201914654)

Also, online you can read [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Comment: +1 for the bit twiddling hacks

Answer (score 2):

Wiki articles:

[Boolean algebra (introduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(introduction)))

[Boolean algebra (logic)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(logic))

[Boolean logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any books on this subject, but here are some online resources... It sounds to me like what you want is to understand binary better to start with.  Here is a little treatment of [Binary](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Binary.html) from MathWorld, which is the web's best mathematics reference.  Here is an applet on [binary shift](http://www.geocities.com/gnashes30/java/applets/binary_shift.htm).  There is a wikipedia article on [Bitwise Operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). Ben Fry has created a good [calculator](http://scicalc.belfry.com/) that includes Bit Roll (Rotation) in it - be sure to look at the help on the calculator as it does much more than is obvious at first - try changing the Mode to Bin, for example.

Answer (score 0):

At university we used a book called [Introduction to Logic Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073191647). Covered everything from boolean algebra up to FPGA stuff. Pretty comprehensive and it has a fair amount of exercises.

Comment: thanks but i need a "crash course" ,that's too comprehensive and i'm not interested in electro..anyway,thanks lot

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C like languages you can also read this: [bitwise operations in C](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1563.asp)

Answer (score 0):

When I took my first digital logic class, I actually did every single lab in Minecraft. This might not help alot of people, who have built many different things here.

I recommend minecraft for some fun hands on experience in this stuff, even though, it may not be the most 'efficient' way to learn :)